# How to read in txt file outside of project folder with Java Netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans, file-io

I want to read in/access a txt file outside of my main project folder in Netbeans.
For example,

```
Project Folder
    ->src
    ->bin
Txt File
```

My project folder and txt file are on the same level(in the same folder).

The project is located in Documents/ComputerPrograms/489/ProjectName The txt file is located in Documents/ComputerPrograms/489/txtFile.txt

Usually I would use

```
./txtfile.txt
```

if the txt file was located within the Project Folder. 
Also, I want to do this using a relative path not an absolute path.

Comment: @codeNinja I have tried BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txtfile.txt")); and BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./txtfile.txt"));

Comment: are you including the full name e.g. txtfile.txt?

Comment: @tommyknocker yes I am, I just used the word txt file for general purposes

Comment: Curious, are you trying this whole loading of a file as part of a bigger application that includes a GUI, if so, you should look into JFileChooser, that streamlines the process of searching for a specific file. i.e. if you want users to select a specific file to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is it, relative to relative to the project, to find it relative it would be

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new File("hierarchy relative to project folder, ex; "bin/com/me/proj/hello"));
```

Comment: The project is located in Documents/ComputerPrograms/489/ProjectName   The txt file is located in Documents/ComputerPrograms/489/txtFile.txt

Comment: Then you would put in `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("txtFile.txt")));`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually was able to but two dots instead of one and it worked. ../txtFile.txt